# How to make feather down in the image?

Tags: css

I have a image, which require the feathering effect in the bottom. how to make that using `css3` alone.

as a example i placed both my `feathered` and `no-feathered` image in the `demo`

[image: with feather]

[image: Without feather]
any one please suggest me the correct way to add feather in the bottom?

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LTdv04LziT2P862tC8Fh?p=preview)

Comment: Just add a gradient over it? What have you tried?

Comment: The images are different heights so it makes it harder to create the desired effect. If you replace the bottom image with one identical to the top but without your effect on it it will be easier to recreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 Gradients was used to achieve the feather effect here. Since the feather is on the bottom, you can use `linear-gradient`'s value `to bottom` with percentage values. i.e. at various stoppage levels.

Change the `opacity` at each stoppage level to achieve a smoother effect.

```css
.shadow {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/Feather/withFeather.png) no-repeat;
  height: 216px;
  width: 215px;
}
.no-shadow {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(22, 49, 102, 0) 0%, rgba(22, 49, 102, 0) 80%, rgba(22, 49, 102, 0.99) 87%, rgba(22, 49, 102, 1) 100%), url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/Feather/withoutFeather.png);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 216px;
  width: 215px;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-shadow"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Both you are using `with feather` png images. there is no gradient working here.

Comment: Can you remove the `withFeather.png` image from the div. still i am not getting result.

Comment: Updated the code, there was a syntax error in `linear-gradient`